# Creating advanced structure with neast and arrays in golang

Tags: arrays, struct, go

Hi guys I am trying to learn golang I am creating my own project which requires to create structure that I have hard times to write and initalized. I would be greatful if anyone can help me out with it.

```
 {
    "name":"message",
    "args":[
        {
            "method":"joinChannel",
            "params":{
                "channel":"CHANNEL",
                "name":"USERNAME",
                "token":"XXXX",
                "isAdmin":false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I was looking for some examples on google but only thing I could find was easie ones. This is what I came up

```
type Channel struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Args []struct {
        Method string `json:"method"`
        Params struct {
            Channel string `json:"channel"`
            Name string `json:"name"`
            Token string `json:"token"`
            Isadmin bool `json:"isAdmin"`
        } `json:"params"`
    } `json:"args"`
}
```

Is there more transparent way to do it?

Comment: I personally think it's a lot more clear if you don't define nested types in line. IE you would define an `Arg` type and a `Params` type then inside here it would have `Args []Arg`, but that's just me.

Comment: How can I do it exactly, sorry I am really newbie :<

Comment: not a problem, I just posted the expanded type declarations as an answer.

Comment: I liked the OP's original attempt best. Admittedly I'm thinking of aws in xml type responses, where you always throw away the first two levels of the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to break the types out rather than having those anonymous declarations inline it would look like this;

```
type Channel struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Args []Arg `json:"args"`
}

type Arg struct {
    Method string `json:"method"`
    Params Params `json:"params"`
}

type Params struct {
      Channel string `json:"channel"`
      Name string `json:"name"`
      Token string `json:"token"`
      Isadmin bool `json:"isAdmin"`
}


myChan := Channel{"Name", []Arg{ Arg{"Method", Params{ "Channel", "Name", "Token", true } } } }
```

Comment: Thank you very much if this it not a lot I have one more question how can I initializ this structure ?

Comment: @user3398940 sure. Not a very readable example, but enough to give you the basic idea. You could also initialize items separate from one another and then assign a `[]Arg` to `Args` when you initialize an instance of `Channel` just as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate nested struct like this.

http://play.golang.org/p/ghcMuFOdQC